# How to wait for networking before runinng a task at startup on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to have a task wait for networking to be ready before running? The only networking related option that I see is "Start only if the following network connection is available", which skips the task if networking isn't ready instead of delaying the task.

If there isn't a way to have the task scheduler wait, is there a command that will block until networking is ready?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a script (say Powershell) as the task target, and get the script to test/wait before firing the desired command(s).

```
do {
  $ping = test-connection -comp <servername> -count 1 -Quiet
} until ($ping)
// Launch task command(s) here.
```

Replace  with the host name or IP address of the host you want to wait for to be ready.

`test-connection` will ping the target device and if it responds $ping will be "True", otherwise "False".

The `do...until` loop will repeatedly ping until it gets a response.  Currently this is endless if it never answers, so you may want to consider changing the loop type and/or adding a max retry limit of some kind.